# How to insert dynamic text into a Wicket page

Tags: wicket

I have a page like this:

```
<html>
<body>
Foo
</body>
</html>
```

I want to use Wicket to replace the word "Foo" with "Bar", like this:

```
<html>
<body>
Bar
</body>
</html>
```

I cannot figure out how to do that. I don't want any HTML escaping on "Bar", and I don't want any tags placed around it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to Wicket!
You need to use a Label component for the dynamic text. See http://wicket.apache.org/guide/guide/helloWorld.html#helloWorld_3. Or just create the application with the Maven archetype (http://wicket.apache.org/start/quickstart.html) - it has a label for the version of Wicket. Just replace the text with "Bar"

Comment: Following the helloWorld tutorial puts a div tag around Bar. Is there any way in Wicket to dynamically find and replace text on an HTML page without putting a tag around it?

Comment: Everything is possible. Do you have some specific way in mind?

Comment: When I create the Label object in Java, is there something I could do like label.setRenderTags( false )? Or maybe in the markup, there could be tags around Foo like <wicket:notag>Foo</wicket:notag> which would be replaced without a tag? Or possibly get the contents of the <body> tag, do a find and replace in Java, and then replace the contents with the modified string?

Comment: Either use label.setRenderBodyOnly(true) or <wicket:component wicket:id="blah"/>

Comment: Thank you martin! The setRenderBodyOnly is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I am curious about the <wicket:component> tip you offered - when I try that, I get this error: Unknown tag name with Wicket namespace: 'component'. Might be you haven't installed the appropriate resolver? '<wicket:component wicket:id="helloMessage">'

Comment: Sorry. I meant <wicket:container>.